# groovy print environments from groovy.config

Tags: groovy

how do I print available environments from a config file?  What is the form of the ojbect ConfigSlurper creates?

I tried

```
def config2 = new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File('obieeadmincfg.groovy').toURL())

config2.config.environments.each { println ${it} }
        and 
println prettyPrint(toJson(config2))
        and
for ( i in 0 ..config2.config.environments.size()-1)
    println config2.config.environments[i]
```

groovy.config

```
//Config3.groovy
obieadmin {
    //default values
    serverurl = "http://default.mycompany.com"

}

environments {
    pldev01 {
        obieeadmin {
            serverurl = 'devgdwobi03.x.com'

        }
    }
    plsbx02 {
        obieeadmin {
            serverurl = 'devgdwobi03.x.com'

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't do this out-of box.

But using a bit of Groovy Metaprogramming it's achievable.
Groovy config slurper parses proper Groovy file, and you can do the same with `GroovyShell`. You can catch call to `environment` method providing closure in binding. In that closure you have to collect all top-level method calls(with same `methodMissing`).
Providing base script with property and method missing handlers, you can suppress runtime errors, and execute script without much care to other properties.

Not the nicest path, but it works.

```
package test
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilerConfiguration

class A extends Script {
    def propertyMissing(String name) { null }
    def propertyMissing(String name, def arg) {}
    def methodMissing(String name, def args) {}
    @Override Object run() { null }
}

class NameCollector {
    def envs = []
    def methodMissing(String name, def args) { envs << name }
}

// configure interceptors.
def configuration = new CompilerConfiguration()
configuration.scriptBaseClass = 'test.A'
def nc = new NameCollector()
def environments = { Closure it ->
        it.delegate = nc;
        it.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY
        it()
}
// execute config script
new GroovyShell([environments: environments] as Binding, configuration).evaluate(new File("config.groovy"))
nc.envs // Return, print them.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is going to work forever but currently you can do it by overriding the setting for the `'environments'` conditional block, like this:

```
def config = """environments {
  dev {
    foo = "bar"
  }
  prod {
    foo = "baz"
  }
}"""

def configSlurper = new ConfigSlurper()
configSlurper.registerConditionalBlock('environments', null)
assert configSlurper.parse(config).environments.keySet() == ['dev', 'prod'].toSet()
```